# Installing Octave 4.2.0 from source on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, octave

I'm trying to build octave 4.2.0 from source, but couldn't due to dependencies.

I'm following instructions at [Obtaining the Dependencies Automatically](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.0/Obtaining-the-Dependencies-Automatically.html#Obtaining-the-Dependencies-Automatically).

but I'm unable to install and am getting following error:

```
You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

I need help to build octave on ubuntu?

Comment: This isn't really a suitable question for SO. You're probably much better off asking this on the octave help mailing list (or even at the #octave irc channel).

Comment: This sounds like your sources.list is empty? You've to first fix your apt and then follow the instruction in the manual and/or http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if u want to compile from source make sure this all dependence are installed:

```
sudo apt-get openjdk-8-jdk gcc g++ gfortran libpcre3-dev libqhull-dev libbz2-dev libhdf5-dev libfftw3-dev libsndfile1-dev libglpk-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev libgraphicsmagick1-dev libgraphicsmagick++1-dev libparpack2 libncurses5-dev libreadline6-dev libsqlite3-dev tix-dev libssl-dev gperf flex bison gnuplot libfltk1.3-dev libarpack++2-dev libqrupdate-dev libosmesa6-dev libqscintilla2-qt5-dev libqscintilla2-dev  qttools5-dev-tools libxft-dev libgl2ps-dev libgdbm-dev liblzma-dev libffi-dev  libsundials-dev
```

or you could just do `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` to install all the above dependences though its not the best way to do so as the [Wiki Octave Page](http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems) explains

Then :

```
## wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-<version-preferred>
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.4.1.tar.xz

## tar xf octave-<version-preferred>
tar xf octave-4.4.1.tar.xz

## rm octave-<version-preferred>
rm octave-4.4.1.tar.xz

## cd octave-<version-preferred>/
cd octave-4.4.1/

./configure
make -j8
sudo make install
```

Comment: First command can be replaced by `sudo apt-get build-dep octave`

Comment: build successfully. sudo apt-get build-dep octave doesn't seem to work, but all depedencies listed above was all that was needed, so thanks.

Comment: Trying those dependencies on Lubuntu 17.04, it is unable to locate packages libbtf1.2.1, libcsparse3.1.4, libhdf5-cpp-11, libjasper-dev, libklu1.3.3, libldl2.2.1, libspqr2.0.2, and llvm-3.5-dev. Any ideas?

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep octave` did seem to help for the previous. With a bit of tweaking, was able to get it compiled and installed. But it was not "easy."

Comment: What about forge packages? I keep getting terminate called after throwing an instance of 'octave::execution_exception' at the end of compilation from octave. Seems I'm stuck with old version :(

Comment: Answer is outdated. Many dependencies can not be found any more.

Answer (score 4):

You can try out this for version 4.2.1:

First remove any version of Octave if present

```
sudo apt-get remove octave
```

then do the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```